# while using python selenium , the entering password part didn't work

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I got some problems while using selenium in Python

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pyperclip
import time
#크롬 드라이버 자동업데이를 위함
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
#브라우저가 자동으로 꺼질 경우 방지 코드 
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('detach', True)
#크롬 드라이버 최신 버전을 설치 후 서비스 객체를 만듦
service = Service(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
#웹페이지 오픈을 위한 옵션들
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.maximize_window()
#웹페이지 주소로 이동
driver.get("https://nid.naver.com/nidlogin.login?mode=form&url=https://www.naver.com/")
#아이디 입력
id = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#id')
id.click()
    
pyperclip.copy('myid')
id.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'v')
time.sleep(2)
    
#비밀번호 입력
pw = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#pw')
pw.click()
pyperclip.copy('mypw')
    
pw.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'v')
time.sleep(2)
login_btn  = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#log\.login')
login_btn.click()
```

that's my code. it successfully opened the web browser but it didn't enter the password.

thanks for reading this, have a good day

I am just a freshman, and I got no idea to fix it because I did my best to find which line was wrong.
the funny thing is it worked on my friend's Windows OS computer. I'm using mac OS, m1 pro chip.
first I tried to update the Chrome web driver automatically and it didn't work.
I finally tried to copy other Chrome driver connection code from the file which worked but nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this way:

```py
# Import necessary modules and classes from the Selenium library
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions, Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

# Configure Chrome options
chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])

# Initialize the Chrome driver using the ChromeDriverManager and the configured options
driver = Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options)

# Initialize a WebDriverWait object to wait for specific conditions
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# Open the specified URL using the Chrome driver
driver.get("https://nid.naver.com/nidlogin.login?mode=form&url=https://www.naver.com/")

# Find the username input field by its ID and wait until it's present, then input the username
username = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'id')))
username.send_keys('your_username')  # Replace 'your_username' with your actual username

# Find the password input field by its ID and wait until it's present, then input the password
password = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'pw')))
password.send_keys('your_password')  # Replace 'your_password' with your actual password

# Simulate pressing the Enter key to submit the login form
password.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: THANK YOU ! It worked. i tried this out and it worked.really thanks i wonder why the browser doesn't closed when i put 'input()' at the end of the code. the code you gave closed directly after the login process. for more, to avoid capcha, i tried to use pyperclip like this :

Comment: pyperclip.copy('usernameexample')
username_send_keys(keys.CONTROL,'v')

timesleep(2)

after editing the code like this, it doesn't works again... my brain got NUMBED

Comment: As I can see, once we enter the username and password, it asks us to solve the captcha which is a complex one to fix as it'll require the usage of computer-vision with NLP to answer the question asked in the captcha image.

Answer (score 0):

Refer the below simplified code:

Assuming you are using at least selenium `v4.6.0` or higher, as I have removed `ChromeDriverManager` from your code.

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])

driver = Chrome(options=chrome_options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

driver.get("https://nid.naver.com/nidlogin.login?mode=form&url=https://www.naver.com/")

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "id"))).send_keys("username")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "pw"))).send_keys("password")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "log.login"))).click()
```

Comment: Your code is wonderful! i almost cried because i was so impressed that you made it so simplified lol... Excuse me but i have few more questions. i wonder why the browser doesn't closed when i put 'input()' at the end of the code. and, i must find out how to avoid capcha and i tried to use pyperclip for this.

Comment: and- it didn't worked... i got no idea ...